# openlayers - export map to canvas problem

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, export, mapcontrol

I am trying to make a export control to export the map as image file.
I found this example: 
http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/exportMapCanvas.html
so i added the control to the map and the function

```
function exportMap() {
    var canvas = OpenLayers.Util.getElement("exportedImage");
    exportMapControl.trigger(canvas);
}
```

I also added the ExportMap.js file:

```
http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Control/ExportMap.js
```

but, i am getting this error, when i am trying to run exportMap():

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided. ExportMap.js:128
```

What that mean? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `useCanvas` property for every layer you want to export with ExportMap.js.

> `useCanvas: OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.ONECANVASPERLAYER`

See this example and its source code: [Export map as image](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/exportMapCanvas.html)

I have successfully exported `WMS` , `WFS` and `Vector` layers but can't export `Google Maps layer`. If you can export `Google Maps layer` then let me know that.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it, what about osm layer? And how I add it to the osm layer?

Comment: I didn't try OSM yet. @Jordan

Comment: @Moshii What OpenLayers version are you using?

Comment: @Jordan Did you ever get it working?  I am having the same problem as you.

Answer (score 2):

I bump this post.

The answer given by Moshii works only if you use a custom version of OpenLayers (the same as [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/exportMapCanvas.html)), because in a standard version of OpenLayers 2 such as 2.13, the ONECANVASPERLAYER does not exist in OpenLayers.Layer.Grid, same for useCanvas.

The possibility of using canvas for WMS Layer was actually an experimentation as you can read [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Future/OpenLayersWithCanvas).

Anyway, OpenLayers 3 has a built-in export function right now.

Comment: Too bad OpenLayers 3 is missing so much other features only found on 2.x.  Would be nice to be able to use this export functionality on OpenLayers 2.x.